# Set columnWeight on EditText

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

I'm using a GridLayout in my activity and I used a couple EditText to fill the grid. The width and everything looked good. Now I want to add the EditTexts dynamic to the existing GridLayout. But I have some problems to translate the XML attributes to Java. Especially I don't know how to set the columnWeight correct.

This is the GridLayout:

```
<GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/cellGrid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnCount="8"
                android:rowCount="5">
...
</GridLayout>
```

This was one of the correct looking XML EditTexts:

```
<EditText
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:background="@color/middelGrey"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />
```

And this is how I try to add the EditTexts to the Grid in a for-loop

```
for(int i=0; i < amountOfCells/2; i++){
        EditText editText = new EditText(getContext());

     editText.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.middelGrey, null));
        editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
        llp.setMargins(0, 0, 2, 2);
        editText.setLayoutParams(llp);
        editText.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        editText.setWidth(20);
        editText.setHeight(wrap_content);
        gridLayout.addView(editText, i);
    }
```

But it doesn't look like the xml version, I think the columnWeight is not set correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set following layout parameters instead of yours:

```
GridLayout.LayoutParams parem = new LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f),  GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f));
```

This can be found here: [Link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/android/widget/GridLayout.java#GridLayout.spec%28int%2Cfloat%29)